# Best way to handle path with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pathlib

When I have a `pd.DataFrame` with paths, I end up doing a lot of `.map(lambda path: Path(path).{method_name}`, or `apply(axis=1)` e.g:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'base_dir': ['dir_A', 'dir_B'], 'file_name': ['file_0', 'file_1']})
    .assign(full_path=lambda df: df.apply(lambda row: Path(row.base_dir) / row.file_name, axis=1))
)
  base_dir file_name     full_path
0    dir_A    file_0  dir_A/file_0
1    dir_B    file_1  dir_B/file_1
```

It seems odd to me especially because `pathlib` does implement `/` so that something like `df.base_dir / df.file_name` would be more pythonic and natural.

I have not found any `path` type implemented in pandas, is there something I am missing?

#### EDIT

I have found it may be better to once for all do sort of a `astype(path)` then at least for path concatenation with `pathlib` it is vectorized:

```
(
    pd.DataFrame({'base_dir': ['dir_A', 'dir_B'], 'file_name': ['file_0', 'file_1']})
    # this is where I would expect `astype({'base_dir': Path})`
    .assign(**{col_name:lambda df: df[col_name].map(Path) for col_name in ["base_dir", "file_name"]})
    .assign(full_path=lambda df: df.base_dir / df.file_name)
)
```

Comment: how about ```df['full_path'] = df['base_dir']+'/'+df['file_name']``` ?

Comment: What is my answer missing?

Comment: it uses the `apply` I was trying to avoid.

Comment: that's strange why w'd you not want to use apply. That's actually contrary to how one w'd think it. But otherwise, what's the problem with apply? Even in what I have done you can do apply(lambda x:os.path.join([x[i] for i in df.columns]) kind of stuff.

Comment: I have also updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the easiest way would be:

```
df.base_dir.map(Path) / df.file_name.map(Path)
```

It saves the need for a lambda function, but you still need to map to 'Path'.

Alternatively, just do:

```
df.base_dir.str.cat(df.file_name, sep="/")
```

The latter won't work on Windows (who cares, right? :) but will probably run faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
   
df = pd.DataFrame({"p1":["path1"],"p2":["path2"]})
df.apply(lambda x:os.path.join(x.p1, x.p2), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
0    path1\path2
dtype: object
```

Edit:

After being told to not use assign you can try this

[See .to_json() docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html)

```
import os
import pandas as pd       
df = pd.DataFrame({"p1":["path1", "path3"],"p2":["path2", "path4"]})
print(df.to_json(orient="values"))
```

Output

```
[["path1","path2"],["path3","path4"]]
```

From here it's simple, just use `map(lambda x:os.path.join(*x), ...)` and you get a list of paths.

Comment: My previous answer was bad according to the docs. Never modify dataframe while iterating with iterrows.

Answer (score 0):

### Using [`pandas-path`](https://github.com/drivendataorg/pandas-path/)

The `pandas-path` package the functionality you need and more. Just by importing, it adds a `.path` accessor to `pd.Series` and `pd.Index` to make `pathlib` methods available.

```py
import pandas as pd
import pandas_path

df =  pd.DataFrame({'base_dir': ['dir_A', 'dir_B'], 'file_name': ['file_0', 'file_1']})

# .path accessor added by importing pandas_path
df.base_dir.path / df.file_name.path

#> 0    dir_A/file_0
#> 1    dir_B/file_1
#> dtype: object
```

<sup>Created at 2021-03-06 18:09:44 PST by [reprexlite](https://github.com/jayqi/reprexlite) v0.4.2</sup>