# Take dates and times from multiple columns to one datetime object with Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got a dataset with multiple time values as below.

```
Area,Year,Month,Day of Week,Time of Day,Hour of Day
x,2016,1,6.0,108,1.0
z,2016,1,6.0,140,1.0
n,2016,1,6.0,113,1.0
p,2016,1,6.0,150,1.0
r,2016,1,6.0,158,1.0
```

I have been trying to transform this into a single datetime object to simplify the dataset and be able to do proper time series analysis against it.

For some reason I have been unable to get the right outcome using the datetime library from Python. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

#### Update - Example of stats here.

https://data.pa.gov/Public-Safety/Crash-Incident-Details-CY-1997-Current-Annual-Coun/dc5b-gebx/data

I don't think there is a week column. Hmm. I wonder if I've missed something?

Any suggestions would be great. Really just looking to simplify this dataset. Maybe even create another table / sheet for the causes of crash, as their's a lot of superfluous columns that are taking up a lot of data, which can be labeled with simple ints.

Comment: what is the code that you've tried with?

Comment: So which week is it? You have day of week, but no indicator which week it is.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects Have you tried to use this? And then maybe the following approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/62488169/4213362

Comment: Seem like they don't provide the actual date of the crash. Maybe for privacy reasons.

Comment: Yes that definitely seems right